# What is the Thomson Reuters tool that is used in universities?

Tags: soft-question, software

I'm not an economics major but when I go to the library of the economics department I see that computers have access to something that is related to Thomson Reuters. given that I'm interested in finance, can somebody explain what is that tool, what can be done with it? and just give some info to somebody like me who doesn't know much. thank you so very much in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about economics.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open, as it can be of help for several economics students, and it refers to a source for economic data.

Comment: "Thomson Reuters" is just a media company. If you've ever read a Reuters article then you'll have had contact with it. I am closing this question because there is not enough information to know exactly what "tool" is being referred to within this person's university system that is associated with the company. It is also not really about economics as within the scope of the site.

Comment: He is very obviously not reffering to the Reuters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuters the international news organization but a specialized service for finance. He doesn't know much, that's why the question is vague, but he assumed correctly that many economists would figure out what he probably means and Kolmogorovwannabe gave a good answer already.

Answer (score 4):

It is a huge financial database which consents you to export data easily via the datastream tool for excel. There you can find common data (such as those available via online databases, e.g. yahoo finance or investing) but also intra-day data, indexes, analysis and the platform consent you to apply directly some statistical techniques. It is a great source, useful especially when you cannot get data from free sources.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the Thomson Reuters database Datastream that is used in many empirical studies as can be seen here? http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Datastream

Answer (score 0):

If you work with financial data, it's a great tool because it provides formated data. That's why many departments provide their students access to it.